# Json Output conflict with HTML editor data PHP

Tags: php, json

In my database have some data those are come from tinymce Editor . If I am copying some data from some website then paste it to my editor and save it to database then its look like

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><strong>Knife Rights is pleased to welcome Alan Gottlieb, Founder of the Second Amendment Foundation and Chairman of the Citizens Committee for the Right to Keep and Bear Arms, as the featured speaker at the Knife Rights Sharper Future&trade; Awards Breakfast at BLADE Show on Saturday, June 7th. Join us for an informative and stimulating start to your Saturday at BLADE Show.</strong></p>
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><strong><font color="#CC0000">Seating is Limited!</font></strong>&nbsp;<a style="color: #0000cc; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.kniferights.org/index.php?option=com_content&amp;task=view&amp;id=106"><strong>Buy your Sharper Future&trade; Awards Breakfast tickets now!</strong></a>&nbsp;<strong><font color="#CC0000">Tickets will NOT be available at BLADE Show or at the door. Tickets are only available online from Knife Rights.</font></strong>&nbsp;<a style="color: #0000cc; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.kniferights.org/index.php?option=com_content&amp;task=view&amp;id=106"><strong>Buy your tickets NOW!</strong></a></p>
<p><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">- See more at: http://www.kniferights.org/#sthash.X2uomQY9.dpuf</span></p>
```

Now when i want to show my array in  JSON output then IT shows error

```
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting '{', '['
```

my code is

```
    $output = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
                'result' => $info           
            );

echo json_encode($output);
```

here $info have data of my editor data.

Comment: Why are you encoding large chunks of html as json?

Comment: cause I have need to show  my data as a api that will be json format @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: it looks like you have an error somewhere else... can't see any problem with this code

Comment: Check what is the complete response. Sometimes, your PHP may output some errors generated and, of course it will not be in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the individual variable:

```
  $output = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => json_encode($message),
            'result' => $info           
        );
```

This assumes that your HTML is in $message.